# jrxml files are not compiling using ant

Tags: ant, jasper-reports

When I tried to compile jrxml files using ANT script the out is showing build successful but no jasper is comipled. the destination folder is empty.

Here is my out put.

D:\Build\Automated Build Script\test>ant

Buildfile: D:\Build\Automated Build Script\test\build.xml

task_definition:

Jasper_reports:

init:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds

My code is...

```
<path id="jasper-ant-classpath">                    
  <fileset dir="${buildBranchPath}/build/web/WEB-INF/lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
<taskdef name="jrc" classname="net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask" >   
   <classpath refid="jasper-ant-classpath"/>        
</taskdef>

<target name="Jasper_reports" depends="task_definition"> 
  <mkdir dir="./build/reports"/> 
  <jrc srcdir="${reportDir}/reports-src/Billing"  
   destdir="./build/reports"
   tempdir="./build/reports"
   keepjava="true"
   xmlvalidation="true">    

  <include name="*.jrxml"/>

  <classpath refid="jasper-ant-classpath"/>
  </jrc>
</target>
```

the ${buildBranch}/build/web/WEB-INF/lib also contains jasperreports-5.0.1.jar file.

Please suggest what is going wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

my code is working fine now and I am able to compile jrxml files.
The srcdir path was not referred properly, once i corrected the path it is working fine.